# Responsive-nav won't work

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm having a bit o dificulty making this work.
This is my first website, I'm using Zurb and finding it good so far.
I'm trying to implement a responsive nav, but it isn't working. The one I'm trying is this one: http://responsive-nav.com/#instructions. I made everything they ask to, but it still don't work. It's the same as not adding code at all to the website.

Some of the nav's code, if it helps:

```
<div class="row" id="row-top">
    <div class="large-4 small-8 columns logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Laboratório Morales">
    </div> <!-- logo -->

    <div class="large-8 small-12 columns nav">
        <ul class="inline-list menu-principal">
            <li><a href="#">Laboratório</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Exames</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Convênios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Estrutura</a></li>
        </ul> <!-- menu-principal -->
    </div> <!-- menu-principal div -->
</div> <!-- row topo -->
```

Calling in the head, and bottom of body:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-nav.css">  <!-- responsive nav -->
<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>          <!-- responsive nav -->


<script>
    var navigation = responsiveNav("#nav");
</script>  <!-- responsive nav -->
```

Comment: I have already built a good part of it with Zurb. I couldn't decide between the two, but I choose Foundation, is that bad?

Comment: The HTML is useful, but we need to also see the JS or CSS you're using to make it responsive. Could you add it please?

Comment: I added how I'm calling them in the original post. DACrosby, I'm using this one: https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm ... you are passing an id *#nav*. But you put *nav* in the class property. It should be

```
<div class="large-8 small-12 columns" id="nav">
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I feel so dumb right now haha
Thanks a lot Krasimir!
It not "kind of" works. It broke the menu inline style and a couple of things, but I think I can figure this part out.
Again, thanks a lot :D